# Build trigger by a comment in gitlab merge request inside Jenkinsfile

Tags: jenkins, gitlab, jenkins-pipeline

at the moment I am starting the build in Jenkins when a comment is written in the Merge request in Gitlab.
I do it in Jenkins job configuration like
[image]

How can I do that in a declarative jenkinsfile I saw how to do it for push events but not for comments.

```
 triggers {
        gitlab(triggerOnPush: true, triggerOnMergeRequest: true, branchFilterType: 'All')
    }
```

i cannot find anything in the gitlab documentation. 
https://github.com/jenkinsci/gitlab-plugin#job-trigger-configuration

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add to pipeline's gitlab trigger:

```
triggers {
    gitlab(
        ...
        triggerOnNoteRequest: true,
        noteRegex: "restart pipeline",
        ...
    )
}
```

Also set webhook in gitlab to be triggered with "Comments"